# How can you change bookmark selection through selected value from slicer? Is it possible?

Tags: powerbi, analytics, data-analysis, business-intelligence

Its known that we can dynamically change measures, dimensions and filters using selected value function, but is there any way that we can change bookmarks/graphs (bar chart to pie chart) on selection of slicer value. Say for example if ID = 1 then show pie chart if all selected show bar graph?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is currently possible.

There are a number of related requests submitted to Power BI Ideas:

[Conditional hide visuals based on value](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=52c5c1ea-80ed-4e53-a5ce-10cd9779f82e)

[Show/Hide Visualizations based on slicer value](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=e1d462a4-156a-4123-b879-11b0ec486d85)

[Visual Hide and visual Show based on Selection Slicer](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=e6f12bea-9164-4d9b-9668-6a6896bc850b)

[conditionally hide visual based on slicer](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=1caf8262-972a-4c99-ab8f-e81700a296c9)

I recommend voting for these to improve their visibility and the likelihood that Microsoft will consider implementing them in the future.